# I can't link my pygame game to my tkinter GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, pygame

Basically I have created a pygame menu for my game and it will load all other pygame windows when I click on them, however for some aspects like adding a user and so on, I created in a Tkinter GUI. When I click to load them on my pygame it wont load the Tkinter GUI, does anyone know how I can solve this or if there's something I need to add in to make it work.

It acts as if its going to load something but doesn't, the first one called "mathsvaders" loads fine as it a pygame program, but the highscore is in tkinter and doesn't load:

```
pos = 1
while True:
# events
for e in pygame.event.get():
    if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()
    elif e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if e.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            pos += 1
            if pos > 5:
                pos = 1
        elif e.key == pygame.K_UP:
            pos -= 1
            if pos < 1:
                pos = 5
        elif e.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
            if pos == 1:
                import MathsvadersReal
            elif e.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
             if pos == 2:
                import Highscore
            elif pos == 5:
             pygame.quit()
             sys.exit()
```

The code for the form is as follows:

```
import Tkinter import Databaseconnector

 class simpleapp_tk(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent) 
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
      def create_widgets(self):
        # create welcome label
        label1 = Tkinter.Label(self, text = "Hello world")
        label1.grid(row = 0, column = 2, columnspan = 4, sticky = 'E')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = simpleapp_tk(None)
    app.title('my application')
    app.geometry("250x200")
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Just a tip, if you want peoples help you should show code examples.

Comment: It acts as if its going to load something but doesn't, the first one called "mathsvaders" loads fine as it a pygame program, but the highscore is in tkinter and doesn't load:

Comment: Sorry it was meant to say pos == 2, but even so it does not work.

Comment: @SmithJr This snippet isn't enough to see where is the problem, the part where you use the Tkinter functions can be more helpful.

Comment: This is the code for the Tkinter GUI

Comment: I can't be sure because the code around it may address this issue, but if you are still in the while loop, you can hardly maintain a tkinter app

Comment: You could possibly try the tkinter after function and then bind that to the while loop, not sure what you want because this is very vague but this may be what you're looking for...

Answer (score 0):

Your main code imports the `Highscore` module when you want to load highscores, which has two problems:

1. In the `Highscore` module, `__name__` is not equal to `"__main__"`. It is equal to `"Highscore"`. Bescaue of this, a `simpleapp_tk` app is never created and it's `mainloop` method is never called. 
   This is probably the problem you are encountering, but it is not the only problem with this code.
2. the `import` statement caches it's results in `sys.modules`, so this code will only work once. To reload the module, you have to explicitly do so, either by calling `reload(Highscore)` or `del sys.modules["Highscore"]`

Answer (score 0):

You are using two windowing systems here and they both need to process events regularly. You have set up pygame as the main event processing loop (`while True:...`) but it never lets Tk process it's event loop. While you have a call to `app.mainloop` it will never get to process events.
When pygame has no events to process it spins in the `while True` to the end of this loop is a good place to call the Tk `update()` method to allow Tk to process events.
You could also use a timer if your game loop is blocking waiting for events.

The short answer though is to process events for both systems. In pygame, calls to one of the pygame event methods and regular calls to the Tk update method.
eg:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
... other stuff ...
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    ... game code ...
    root.update()
```